# Is making android-tv apps same as making android (mobile/tablets) apps in android studio?

Tags: android

i am going to make my first android app for android T.V and i already know android development. Do i have to learn additional skills to make a app for T.V

Answer (score 0):

You can find a helpful tutorial on how to create Android TV Apps from Android Developers [here](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/index.html).

Creating TV apps is basically the same as creating Android Apps, since it's based on the same framework.

On a TV, you have all your layouts (LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, ...) and stuff like activities as usual, but you have to bear in mind that you are on different hardware. So you (obviously) won't have access to things like gyro sensor.

As you can see [here](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/navigation.html), some navigation is also different than on Android, so you'll have to learn some new things, but I think the tutorial from Android Developers is a good starting point, and from what I've seen it should not be that hard if you are familiar with the Android API.